# C++ can I create derived instead of bass class dependent on arguments given to single constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, derived-class, base-class

If I have a base class with a derived class, is it possible to create instances as either the bass or derived class dependent on arguments passed into a single constructor?

Example Code:

```
//Base Class
class MyClass {
public:
  //All instances created with this constructor
  MyClass(int param1, int param2) {
    if (param1 > param2) { //(for example)
      // TODO - create this object as SubClass instead
    } else {
      //normal base class construction
    }
  }
}

//Derived Class
class SubClass {
public:
  SubClass(int param1, int param2) {
    //Subclass construction
  }

  void function() {
    //function that only works on subclass objects
  }
}

MyClass object1(1, 2); //should create MyClass object
MyClass object2(2, 1); //should create SubClass object
```

As shown above, when an instance of this class is created, I want the constructor to either function normally and make the class, or (dependent on the values given as arguments) make it as an instance of the derived SubClass. Note that it must be based on the values of the different parameters, not just their types. Is it possible to do this? If necessary, it would work to have another derived class to represent the 'normal' option (instead of using the pure bass class), as long as only one constructor ever has to be used.

If this is not possible, I *can* just call the SubClass constructor when I want an instance of this, but this is not ideal as I would have to check which one should be created each time one is created, rather than just having a single internal check within the constructor.

Comment: This is what the factory design pattern is for, you pass the parameters into factory create, and it returns either MyClass or Subclass based on the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate the creation to a static function of `MyClass`:

```
class SubClass;

//Base Class
class MyClass {
  MyClass(int param1, int param2) {
  }
public:
  static unique_ptr<MyClass> Create(int param1, int param2) {
    if (param1 > param2) { //(for example)
      return std::make_unique<SubClass>(param,param2);
    } else {
      return std::make_unique<MyClass>(param,param2);
    }
  }
}

//Derived Class
class SubClass : public MyClass {
  SubClass(int param1, int param2) {
    //Subclass construction
  }
public:

  void function() {
    //function that only works on subclass objects
  }
}

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> object1 = MyClass::Create(1, 2); //should create MyClass object
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> object1 = MyClass::Create(2, 1); //should create SubClass object
```

Comment: Great! Is there any way to make constructions default to the static method? Assuming not, can I throw an exception whenever the constructor is called (unless via the static method), so as to force use of the static method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a fabric. It will return a pointer to the parent class depending on your params. You will work with it via an interface of your parent class. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern